# Sql server массив типа long, int

Tags: sql

В поле таблицы sql server субд надо организовать  массив int или long. Как такое сделать?

Comment: БД-то какая? Судя по тому, что Вы не догадались явно указать, речь идёт о MS SQL Server? :)

Comment: Не менее важна и конкретная версия.

Comment: @sexfactor Для комментариев, лучше использовать комментарии. Для уточнения вопроса, лучше править вопрос, а не создавать уточняющий ответ.

Comment: sqlserver уже как синоним mssql

Answer (score 2):

На этот вопрос нет просто и короткого ответа. Почитайте [вот тут](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html), но мой совет: лучше не заморачиваться. Заведите строковое поле и сериализуйте в него массив.

Comment: у строки какой лимит? в sqlserver типа text

Comment: Если сделать отдельную таблицу, где бы реализовался массив это было правильным?
Например: 
categoryid   podcategoryid
1               2
1               4
1               3
.....

Или text заюзать правильней?
 

Comment: Можно сделать и так. Этот вариант рассматривается в статье, на которую я дал ссылку.

Comment: И ещё. Не переспрашивайте ответами на свой вопрос. Правильнее использовать комментарии.

Comment: Сорри за возможно дурацкий, но разв в mssql нельзя как в оракле объявить тип, являющийся array of number ?

Comment: Ну а зачем? Там же есть таблицы!

Comment: Таблицы в таблицах? Или вы имеет в виду две таблицы?

Comment: Я имею в виду отдельную таблицы для массива. Ну по ссылке же есть пример! Да и автор вопроса, судя по всему, представляет, как это делается.

Answer (score 0):

Какие действия подразумеваются с этим полем?

Если в самом сервере не нужно будет оперировать отдельными элементами массива, то я бы хранил массив в бинарном поле. Это более компактно и быстрее чем в строковом.

А если все таки операции с отдельными числами массива в sql потребуются, то лучше завести таблицу и хранить в отдельной записи одно значение, чем заморачиваться с разбором бинарного (или строкового - одинаково геморойно) поля.

Comment: Какие-такие заморочки с разбором?

Comment: язык sql плохо приспособлен к работе с неструктурированными данным, т.е. как раз к тем которые хранятся в таких сложных полях (бинарных или строковых).

Comment: есть такое... он мне небольшой xml с несколькими тысячами узлов разбирал минут двенадцать. после упихивания тех же данных в более жесткий формат и написания запроса, вытаскивающего данные из этой строки в виде таблицы, справляется за 0.1 секунды.

Answer (score 0):

Мы используем для работы с массивами в БД xml.

Скорее всего, долгий разбор xml, о котором пишет maxleo, связан с тем, что результат этого разбора после этого сразу использовался в неком запросе.

Sql Server автоматом не оптимизирует запросы, в которых используется функция OPENXML. Он выполняет их так, чтобы максимально её обойти. Отсюда могут быть тормоза. Чтобы их не было, результат выполнения функции OPENXML следует поместить во временную таблицу и уже её использовать в запросах. Объёмы данных, которые при этом могут не влезть в память, в xml не хранят, если возникает такая проблема, следует пересмотреть дизайн.

Comment: А мы используем мускул и постгрю и вообще все шикарно без гемора :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно объявить переменную табличного типа (тот же массив, но баз данных), и добавлять значения в нее, н.п.:

```
declare @myArray table(value int)
```

для добавления значений в нее:

```
insert into @myArray (value) values (1), (2), (3)
```

для выборки из нее:

```
select * from @myArray
```